# Imidazoline receptor agonist in clonidine?

Tags: pharmacology, central-nervous-system

I am thinking which pathway is more important in hypertension, ADHD and withdrawal of clonidine:

- alpha-2 agonist
- imidazoline receptor agonist (maybe)

Alpha-2 is the classical one. Pubchem starts to have more more info about imidazoline receptors.

How does clonidine work in hypertension, ADHD and withdrawal?